# Programmatically set "for" attribute on HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am building some menus using `document.createElement` and have recently found the need to create radio buttons. I'd like for these to be easily clickable by using associated labels and the `for` attribute. However, the `for` attribute is not carried through to the rendering, and I can't seem to find how this is supposed to be set. It does work after editing the rendered HTML in the inspector, so all I need is to have it set properly.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
var l = document.createElement('label');
var i = document.createElement('input');
var id = element.type + "_" + (Math.random() * 100);
i.id = id;
l.innerHTML = choice.name;
l.for = id; // nope
```

Which generates this markup:

```
<input id="radio_50.88489994434866" type="radio" value="Combined" name="layer_radios">
<label>Combined</label> <!-- no "for" attribute -->
```

How can I set this attribute?

Comment: [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) maybe?

Comment: It's "htmlFor", not "for"

Comment: 1. `for` is a keyword. Do not use it like this. 2. If the attribute is not "standard", you set it with `setAttribute('some name', 'some value')`.

Comment: @CoderCharmander or use the "htmlFor" property directly

Comment: @CoderCharmander - In modern JavaScript, `for` would have been fine. But before ES5, literal property names couldn't be reserved words. (Now they can.) So they used `htmlFor` instead (like `className` for class).

Comment: @CoderCharmander doesn't matter that it's a keyword  `obj = {"for": "you"}` is a valid object and you can access the value through `obj.for`

Comment: A quicker way to get help on problems like this is to check [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement)

Comment: @VLAZ - In ES5 and higher, so is `obj = {for: "you"}`. :-)

Comment: I assume someone checked, and making `for` and `htmlFor` synonymous wasn't websafe, or they'd've done it by now...